# evaluate website that uses es6 in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phantomjs

I would like to evaluate website that uses es6 features (arrow functions) but phantomjs 2.1 does not support it, so page becomes unresponsive and I can't manipulate it. Is there any way to use es6 features in phantomjs <= 2.10 or to overwrite script file before page is loaded so I can use same file without new javascript features?

Comment: Maybe use a newer PhantomJS version, like 2.5b?

Comment: but can I use node-phantom bridge with 2.5b?

Comment: Probably, just provide the path to executable on init